# Reply-to in MIME Lite errors because of using strict [ => (fat comma) operator]

Tags: perl, email, mime

I use MIME::Lite to send emails from my Perl script. I have *use strict;* in my header, since that's standard usage in all our scripts.

```
        my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
            From => $from,
            To   => $to_str,
            Cc      => $cc_str,
            Reply-To    => $replyto,
            Subject => $tf_subject,
            Type    => 'multipart/mixed'
        );
```

I get the following error when I add Reply-To in this function to get the bounce back emails.

**Bareword "Reply" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at**

But I see in the documentation of MIME::Lite that Reply-To is the only way to get the bounce back emails.

Is there a way to accommodate both strict and Reply-To in the same script?

Comment: Should `Reply-To` be a single word ?

Comment: `-` is considered the subtraction operator.

Comment: For what it's worth, `use strict` isn't causing the error; `use strict` is just complaining about the error; if you leave it out, Perl stops complaining, and the program will run but with weird errors that you'll have a lot of trouble debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `Reply-To` in quotes. make it `'Reply-To'`

```
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
  From => $from,
  To   => $to_str,
  Cc      => $cc_str,
  'Reply-To'    => $replyto,
  Subject => $tf_subject,
  Type    => 'multipart/mixed'
);
```

---

**Explanation:**

[man perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop)

> The "=>" operator (sometimes pronounced "fat comma") is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted
> as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores.  This includes operands that
> might otherwise be interpreted as operators, constants, single number v-strings or function calls.  **If in doubt about this behavior, the
> left operand can be quoted explicitly**.
>
> Otherwise, the "=>" operator behaves exactly as the comma operator or list argument separator, according to context.

Comment: That helped. Works for me!

Answer (score 4):

```
        Reply-To    => $replyto,
```

It should be `'Reply-To'` (quoted) not `Reply-To` - unless you want to subtract `To` from `Reply`.